# Replacing two skylights from an array of five, flat-adjacent roof

Tags: roof, decking, skylight

the two skylight have been leaking for quite a while which can be attributed to a poor job by me, improper layering, and mistakes in Forti Flash installation. It is 12 years old; it is a rolled roof application. I think I can start from the beginning OK for the two new curb mounted ones, but am concerned with how to connected up the Forti Flash, felt, roll roofing,etc layers with the existing layers. Sure I can make it work, but want this time to keep it working. I have heard to use the forti flash 1st, underneath the curb, then screw and glue down the curb to that, more forti flash to wrap the thing, starting

Comment: How about some pictures? How about taking the [tour], then an [edit] to ask a question.  So far, you've just made some statements...

Comment: Help us to help you, post some picture